# CSS Bootstrap close modal and go to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following div for a modal box -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Community" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='#Pricing'" data-dismiss="modal">Close and go to pricing</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click of the button the modal window closes but it doesn't go to the correct section indicated by #Pricing.

Comment: why don't you use <a> link

Comment: @rjdmello is right. Use a normal link, there is no need to close the modal when you go to another page anyway...

Comment: I have tried that and it behaves in the same way. And the link is not for another page. Its for the same page with a div with id="#Pricing" . It doesn't go to the required section. Just closes the modal and gets stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the link is in same page just use

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#pricing").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    })
});
```

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbv02x0L/1/)

Comment: What javascript libraries do i need for this? Both bootstrap and jquery?

Comment: @jacksparrow007 yes, you need both

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a `'` in `onclick`.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='#Pricing'" data-dismiss="modal">Close and go to pricing</button>
```

**Update**

I think I get to know the reason. Actually, in your case, `onclick` is fired before `data-dismiss="modal"`. This means, the location change would happen even before the modal dismissal. However, in order to prevent the page from scroll when a modal present, the body will have a `modal-open` class. This takes `overflow: hidden;`, so the page will not be able to scroll more than the height of the modal itself.

To solve this problem, you need to defer your location change to after the modal disappears. You can move it into the callback of the `hidden.bs.modal` event.

The event docs can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage .

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to close the dialog and go to the [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#document_fragments) at the same time:

```
<a href="#foobar">
  <span data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed and I suspect to op should consider it as its the cleanest way to accomplish the close first and the navigate second.

Comment: works in BS4 too, but parameter is `data-dismiss="modal"`

Comment: This looked promising but in the latest version of Bootstrap it behaves really weirdly with the transition and ends up back at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

use this event

```
$('#Community').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // do something...
    window.location.href='/#Pricing'
})
```