# Link within a Bootstrap Modal does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a link inside modal, and I want to take users to a specific location upon clicking. Currently, this works the first time, but any subsequent uses of the same modal when using the "close" button (not the specific link) of the modal, it also sends me to my link (not expected behavior).

Here is a js fiddle that shows the weird behavior of a link in a Bootstrap modal. https://jsfiddle.net/x9kr2wwm/5/

My attempt is a modification of a very similar question/answer (but not a duplicate) found here: [CSS Bootstrap close modal and go to link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118838/css-bootstrap-close-modal-and-go-to-link)

HTML:

```
See the <a href="#getstarted" id="gotoLink" data-dismiss="modal">"Get Started"</a> section for more
```

Javascipt:

```
jQuery(function($) {
            $("a#gotoLink").click(function(){
                $('#portfolioModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#getstarted").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                })
           });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for an `<a>` element is for the page to be redirected to its `href` attribute. To prevent the default behavior, use jQuery's [.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method.

```
jQuery(function($) {
            $("a#gotoLink").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); 

                $('#portfolioModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#getstarted").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                })
           });
    });
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, but still have the unexpected behavior after including the 'event.preventDefault()' . The close button and close-modal still scroll to the bottom of the page as well. Is there a way to tie another event to the '.on(hidden.bs.modal..' event?

Comment: Comment edit - Is there a way to tie another event, like the click event for the gotoLink, to the 'code' .on(hidden.bs.modal event 'code'

Comment: What is the behavior that you want?

Comment: In the modal window, I need the link for "Get Started" to a) close the modal window and b) do the page scroll to the #getstarted section. However, closing the modal window with the "Close Button" or using the "X" also ends up taking the person to the #getstarted section - that is not expected behavior.  thanks again for your help

Comment: Notice how it works the first time clicking the link in the modal. But if you were to use the close button (not the link) in subsequent visits to the modal window, it will also take you to the link, rather than simply just closing the modal like it should. PS sorry for my poor use of comments, i've been using Stack for a long time but a newb to actually interacting on it